# How to target div class within a form?

Tags: html, css

I have this html which i want to target with css. The problem is that i can't find the right css selector.

The problem is that `. entry-content` doesn't work. Neither does.`event-manager-form`. The form itself is a Wordpress event manager form and want to style in with, amongst others,, `border-radius`

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <form action="/post-an-event/" method="post" id="submit-event-form" class="event-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>

      <label>Your account</label>
      <div class="field 
    account-sign-in">
        You are currently signed in as <strong>Bla bla</strong>. <a c class="button" href="...">Sign out</a>.
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Event 
    Information Fields -->
    <h2 class="section-title">Event Details</h2>

    <fieldset class="fieldset-event_title">
      <label for="event_title">Event Title<span class="require-field">*. 
    </span></label>
      <div class="field required-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-text event_title" name="event_title" id="event_title" placeholder="Event title" attribute="" value="" maxlength="" required />
      </div>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-         event_online">
      <label for="event_online">Online Event<span class="require- 
    field">*</span></label>
      <div class="field 
    required-field">
        <label><input 
    type="radio" name="event_online" id="event_online" 
    attribute="" value="yes"  /> Yes</label>
        <label><input 
    type="radio" name="event_online" id="event_online" 
    attribute="" value="no" /> No</label>
```

Comment: What do you want to access? `.account-sign-in` ?

Comment: I want .something {border-radius: 20px;}

Comment: Something what ??? Also you have too many spaces in your classes. For example `fieldset-         event_online`

Comment: so that it targets all the boxes in that form

Comment: I tried `.entry-content {border-radius: 20px;}` didn't work

Comment: `.entry-content input {border-radius: 20px;}`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? if yes then please share the link. Thanks

Comment: https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/

Comment: Hi nac please check below answer.